# bash, how to use OR || operator in If statement?

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax, comparison

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this syntax:

```
if [ "$1" == "postfix" || "$1" == "all" ]; then
    echo test
fi
```

Comment: `[ a == b ] || [ c == d ]` or `[ a == b -o c == d ]`. Or `[[ ... ]]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either

```
if [ "$1" = "postfix" ] || [ "$1" = "all" ]; then
```

or

```
if [ "$1" = "postfix" -o "$1" = "all" ]; then
```

`||` combines two commands (and the `[` is a command).  Within the `[` ... `]` the operator `-o` is used for *or*.

Another way to use `||` is to use it inside `[[` instead of `[`.

In any way, the correct operator for equality is `=` inside `[` ... `]` as it is the POSIX standard (according to `man bash`).  `==` is supported, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this, use `[[` test form :

```
if [[ $1 == "postfix" || $1 == "all" ]; then
```

`[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, we recommend `[[`

or

```
if [ "$1" == "postfix" ] || [ "$1" == "all" ]; then
```

Comment: There's not much difference to my answer, so ⁺¹ from me ;-)